# Xcode Test Target Won't Autocomplete Code Under Test

Tags: xcode, xcode14.3

In Xcode (14.3.1, and earlier) we have a Unit Test Target that tests an iOS application codebase. The code in the test target will compile and successfully execute & pass the unit tests. However, autocompletion in the editor doesn't work, which makes it burdensome to build tests for.

Any ideas on how to fix autocompletion? This happens on two different computers, and I have tried to clear the derived data.